# Background-image is not being displayed

Tags: php, css, wordpress, background-image

I'm pulling a featured image in from a blog post and setting to my background image.  I'm using the same line of code I usually do, but for some reason no image is being displayed.

```
$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');

<div class="panel--bg-image" <?php $img ? print 'style="--background-image: url(' . $img['sizes']['large'][0] . ');"' : ''; ?>>
```

To make sure my variable isn't empty, I ran

```
var_dump($img)
```

and my image is indeed being called. When I check the element in the dev tools, I see this:
[image]

When an image is successfully being called, I can always see the file in the url().  I usually pull these images from a custom filed, but these are being pulled from 'featured image' in the post backend.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the return value of `var_dump($img)`?

Comment: Looks like `$img['sizes']['large'][0]` is evaluated to an empty string.

Comment: The value of the var_dump is an array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The WordPress function `wp_get_attachment_image_src` requires the Image-ID and the size and returns an array:

```
array {
    [0] => url,
    [1] => width
    [2] => height
    [4] => is_intermediate
}
```

So, if you want to get the Image-URL, use `$img[0]` instead of `$img['sizes']['large'][0]`.

Source: [WordPress Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/#user-contributed-notes)